# check if form validation is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Hello i have a form that i want to run through form validation and then submit. How can i check if the following function returns true to know that everything has been validated and then submitted?

## I created a fiddle to test

http://jsfiddle.net/WHGq2/

## MODIFIED CODE

```
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
        $("#form").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                        },
                phone: {
                    equired: true,
                    phone: true
                        }
                    },
            messages: {
                name: "Please let us know who you are.",
                email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
                phone: "Please provide a valid phone number.",
            }
        })  


    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        // Stop the form actually posting
        e.preventDefault();




        // I want to be able to do the check here if the form has passed validation
        if( $(this).valid() ) {
        // Stop the form actually posting

        // Send the request
        $.post('/submit.php', {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        }, function(d){
            alert("Thank you for submitting your request someone will contact your shortly.");
        });
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success

Comment: You can try `if($('#form').valid())`...

Comment: Check my answer, I think it'll be solved for you now.

Answer (score 7):

You can call the valid() method of jquery validation. Like

```
if($('#form').valid())
```

Actually you can declare the validate function when the html page is loaded and just check whether it's valid or not at the time of submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#form').validate(rules...messages...);
```

In case of rules & messages use:-

```
  rules: {
            name: {
               required: true  
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
                    },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phone: true                       }
                },
        messages: {
            name: { required : "Please let us know who you are."},
           email: {required : "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",email : "A valid email will help us get in touch with you."},
            phone: {required:"Please provide a valid phone number.",phone:"Please provide a valid phone number."}
        }
```

It's a good practice and in case of phone numbers, you've misspelled required

```
$('#form').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    .....

    if( $('#form').valid() ) {
       //submit the form via ajax
    } else {
       //show errors
    }
 });

});
```

And I think you know than you've to add the name attribute of each input field:-

```
 <input type="text" name="email" />
```

Comment: This seems to prevent the validation from showing bad data. The preventDefault() shorts out the normal response of highlighting shortcomings.

Comment: This may be the solution: `$(".selector").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
  }
});` I'm going to look into making it work on my page. I'll report back.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that **`required` in the `phone` rule was written `equired` and could have caused most of your issues**. See the demo included.

```
$(function() {

    $('#form').validate(.......);

    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        .....

        if( $(this).valid() ) {
           //submit the form via ajax or otherwise
        } else {
           //report errors
        }
    });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/WHGq2/2/)

Comment: I modified the code and used your suggestion but now it doesn't show any errors and it doesn't submit the form through ajax

Comment: I think defining the validate function when the body is ready will solve the problem.

Comment: Can your create a JSfiddle of the updated code so we can work on it together.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `valid` method of the plugin, something like following.

```
$('#form').validate({...});

if ($('#form').valid()) {
    // do your thing
}
```

here is the documentation http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid

Comment: Think you mean $('#form').valid()

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code, added **submitHandler** ,Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){

        $("#form").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                        },
                phone: {
                    equired: true,
                    phone: true
                        }
                    },
            messages: {
                name: "Please let us know who you are.",
                email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
                phone: "Please provide a valid phone number.",
            },
            submitHandler: function() {  
                      // Stop the form actually posting
                       e.preventDefault();

                     // Send the request
                   $.post('/submit.php', {
                   name: $('#name').val(),
                   email: $('#email').val(),
                   phone: $('#phone').val(),
                   message: $('#message').val()
                   }, function(d){
                        alert("Thank you for submitting your request someone will contact your shortly.");
                   }); 
            }
    });
});
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, it says its missing some bracket somewhere, but for some reason i can't find where its missing at.

Comment: thank you very much,  updated my code, but now it just submits the form and doesn't do any validation and the ajax submit isn't working